# Install PECL extensions Error on DV

Tags: pecl, mediatemple

I'm following the instructions to install PECL Extensions on a Media Temple DV 4 based on these instructions: http://wiki.mediatemple.net/w/(dv):Install_PECL_extensions.

When running:

`pecl install uploadprogress`

It says:

```
pecl install uploadprogress
downloading uploadprogress-1.0.3.1.tgz ...
Starting to download uploadprogress-1.0.3.1.tgz (9,040 bytes)
.....done: 9,040 bytes
4 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
building in /var/tmp/pear-build-root/uploadprogress-1.0.3.1
running: /root/tmp/pear/temp/uploadprogress/configure
checking for egrep... grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details.
ERROR: `/root/tmp/pear/temp/uploadprogress/configure' failed
```

Does anyone have an idea why it's not working and how to resolve it? Thanks!

PS I tried the compile from source option but that also fails and says:

```
phpize && ./configure -with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config
Cannot find config.m4. 
Make sure that you run '/usr/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module
```

To note, I don't know where config.log is located to be able to look in there for more information yet.

[Resolved] White the PECL install never worked and no one here could find the answer, I was able to compile from source eventually once I realized I hadn't cd into the right directory before configuring.

Comment: You need to look at the `config.log` file, which should be in the build directory shown in the output: `building in /var/tmp/pear-build-root/uploadprogress-1.0.3.1`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but sadly there is nothing inside of /var/tmp/pear-build-root/ Maybe it deletes itself while buidling. Still not having any luck finding the config.log :-/

Comment: The other referenced directory was `/root/tmp/pear/temp/uploadprogress`. See what's hanging around in there.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the first thing I checked when I saw the error. /root/tmp/pear/temp/ is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the PECL install never worked and no one here could find the answer, I was able to compile from source eventually once I realized I hadn't cd into the right directory before configuring.